# selecting child react component under div is not working in app.jsx file

Tags: reactjs

**App.jsx**

```
....

<div className="twoItemsRow">
          <Input
            inputType="normal"
            titleText="<Input helperText=”Some interesting text” />"
            headerText="Label"
            footerText="Some interesting text"
            placeHolderText="Placeholder"
          />
          <Input
            className="secondChildComponent"
            inputType="error"
            titleText="<Input helperText=”Some interesting text” error />"
            headerText="Label"
            footerText="Some interesting text"
            placeHolderText="Placeholder"
          />
        </div>

....
```

**App.css**

I wish to style second child component under `<div>` as below

```
..
.secondChildComponent {
  background-color: green;
}
...
```

but it's not working, is my selector wrong or approach is wrong ?

Comment: Can you show code pan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing className to `Input` component props. You should implement this in `Input` component. The react className property would work only on HTML elements.

e.g.

```
const Input = (props) => {
  const {className = ''} = props

  return <input className={`inputClassName ${className}`} />
}
```

Comment: can you please clarify if this is optimum way to style child component under standard html element or there is a better way to do it ?

Comment: This is a tough question. It's not worth a few lines but better an blog post. I was solving your issue and there is nothing bad on this approach. It can differ on the styling solution you are using as well. I recommend you to read a little bit more about it https://www.sitepoint.com/react-components-styling-options/. Personally I'm using Emotion and this solution deals with that problem with composition.